# Date not able to Format(OOP)

Tags: javascript

The function that I am creating right now is to format the date form the console log to DDMMYYYY instead of the given format. However, I am getting this error where is says the getDate is not a function.

> *userDate.getDate is not a function*

How should I go about solving this error?

```
   function formatDate(userDate) {
      let formatted_date = userDate.getDate() + (userDate.getMonth() + 1) + userDate.getFullYear()
      return formatted_date;
    }

    console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

Comment: userDate what u passing  in this param

Comment: getDate() is a Date method, and you're passing a string as argument(userDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `getDate()` on a string reference, you need to convert it first to a `Date` object:

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
    userDate = new Date(userDate);
    let formatted_date = `${userDate.getDate()}/${(userDate.getMonth() + 1)}/${userDate.getFullYear()}`;
    return formatted_date;
}
console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

Comment: @heh that is because at that time you are ***adding*** the values instead of concatenating them together as strings. So I have refactored you code to use template strings instead of using the `+` to concat.

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you for the explanation, now i understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh i'll do it later cuz it says i need to wait 3 minutes. :)